# Appending an onload to an image causes the onload event to be fired multiple times on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-events

I was trying to count the amount of images loaded on the page, because I needed to wait until all images were loaded in order to calculate the correct height of the parent element. I ended finding a much better way of doing this, but I ran into weird behaviour on android devices.

When you append an image with a onload function with jQuery, the event gets fired multiple times on Android:

```
$('#element').append('<img src="/interesting/path" onload="doSomethingWeird()" />' );
```

All other browsers I was working with were not doing this weird behaviour. I've had this on Android's 4.0.4 browser.

Does anybody why this is happening?

Comment: It may be helpful to know what Android browser you're using, since there are a number of them.

Comment: You're right Aaron, I've updated my answer.